# What's the best state machine gem to mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, mongoid, state-machine, mongodb-ruby

What's the best state machine gem to use with mongoid?

Comment: I need something like state_machine https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good one: https://github.com/ryanza/stateflow

Answer (score 6):

The state_machine gem https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine should work with mongoid as it uses active_model